# Randomize content of search list

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, random

I have been using a search list however I want to randomize the order of the items in the list. You should still be able to filter and search but all the regular content that is there before searching will be in a randomized order. The issue I am having is putting together the code. For some reason it isn't working and I can't figure out why. Here is some code for the list and searching

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; 
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>


<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is some code to randomize the order of the items inside the list:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear, when do you want the options to be random?

Comment: If you run the first code before you search for anything, the list items will be in the order you put them in. I want to randomize that first-order while keeping the searching bit of it. When you go to the page before you search anything the order of the list items should be different each time

Comment: So you want to randomize the options every time when the page is refreshed? Is that it?

Comment: Yep that's the solution I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. You need to put the randomizing code in your script.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; 
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```